# Cannot get URI from the URL, getting null?

Tags: java, jar, nullpointerexception

I have a situation where I have a template file(.xls) in my executable jar. No during at runtime I need to create 100s of copy for this file(which would be uniquely appended to later).
For getting the resource (template.xls) within the jar file. I am using

```
URL templateFile=G1G2Launcher.class.getClass().getResource(File.separator+"Template.xls");
            System.out.println("URL-->"+templateFile);
            System.out.println("URI For Source-->"+templateFile.toURI().getPath());
            sourceFile=templateFile.toURI().getPath();
```

I am getting a null value at `templateFile.toURI.getPath()` What could be the possible reason??
This is what I got :

```
URL--> jar:file:/home/eketdik/Desktop/G1G2-KD@Tool.jar!/Template.xls
URI For Source-->null
```

Actually I pass this URI to File constructor to get a File Object for it..(for copying it).
So the stack trace is-->

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.io.File.<init>(File.java:251)
    at gui.Utility.copyfile(Utility.java:29)
    at printer.Printer.printFinalSiteWiseReportsForSignOff(Printer.java:1408)
```

Please suggest where am I going wrong??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

modifying a file of a Jar at runtime is impossible.

So You can get the file as inputstream and then create copies out side the jar.
Below Code helps you to create file same as you want.

```
InputStream in = G1G2Launcher.class.getClass().getResourceAsStream("file.xls")
OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File("file.xls"));
int read = 0;
byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];
while ((read = in.read(bytes)) != -1) {
    out.write(bytes, 0, read);
}
```

Comment: I don't thing this would give me the URL, It only gives me the InputStream opened on that file,Whereas the inbuilt copy function in the application takes two paths,namely source and destination. So this would fail.

Answer (score 0):

Just use [getResourceAsStream(String res)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#getResourceAsStream%28java.lang.String%29).